# CGCC sings a song together

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity, answer-chaining, code-shuffleboard

This is a [code-shuffleboard](/questions/tagged/code-shuffleboard) [answer-chaining](/questions/tagged/answer-chaining) challenge, where the answers will aim to, together, output the lyrics to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) beloved 80s song.

[This](https://tio.run/##7ZTPTsMwDMbveQrftkl7iUlIUy9wRBzTxW3KUnvKn1V9@uGkG6xD3EBigltlO19@/r6owelgMZxOz7jwCMQQotfUog8QGRwfUb1wgj3xANEi@OQwgCYDgcEwVGoDTXIOdtz3XeyR4iLAYHWEatHLkY72HbXATdEZODlDiwgtxtwM0HjuRW8EFnkPbRpVBa8pRBg0kYaIIj7KUSsEWbJBdKKothyjhl7vsbQTGYGOQqbUIx6zFOfzbXc8DxxmdScAuWx4oFnDJwLtWfTKmgYD@jI6m3q/d@fHWSPoUb7Y1CPO6mUPubbDImvTWVSJ80KYDSZAvbNnIxr22WLHsqo458Gi9tnbGlEAdza7WqeYmzm6yJKdHXNqGaGLqqLQGYQBoRbJKcIczEWj5RIMCcFHvq3uJ8ChPIiJ/eAmxY3Uu6asrcMeZPI2lAfO4ZZd@@LPBa2WtilwiHcW0F3BLp/Yrq8xV1@VVp8WWwPdVNRy@w3Hrp74b3/hf@zf8w/7M7Cn0xs) is the full lyrics of the song, line by line.  The first answer will contain a program that will output the first line of the song (`We're no strangers to love`). The second will do the same, but for the second line (`You know the rules and so do I`) and so on. Some answers (the 7th, 14th, 22nd, 29th, 36th, 45th, 51st, 54th, 61st and 68th) will output a blank line.

Each answers' program, however, must be **irreducible**, meaning that it must not output the correct line if any non-zero number of characters (not necessarily consecutive) are removed.

- `print("We're no strangers to love")` is an irreducible Answer 1 in Python 3
- `if 1: print("We're no strangers to love")` is not, as we can remove `if 1:`  and it'll still output the first line
- `print("We're no str" + "angers t" + "o love")` is also not, as the two `" + "`s can be removed, and it'll still produce the correct output.

---

Let \$\bar x_i\$ be the arithmetic mean of the lengths of the first \$i\$ lines, to 1 decimal place. This sequence begins \$26, 28, 32, 34, 34.6, 33\$ and converges to \$\bar x_{74} = 24.3\$ by the end of the song. Each answer has a score, which will eventually determine the overall winner. The score for the \$i\$th answer is defined as:

> If the \$i\$th answer is \$n\$ bytes long, its score is \$|n - \bar x_i|\$

So, if the first answer is 10 bytes long, its score is \$16\$, and if the 72nd answer is 2 bytes long, its score is \$|2 - 24.2| = 22.2\$. A user's overall score is the arithmetic mean of the scores of all their answers. The user with the lowest overall score wins.

[The full sequence](https://tio.run/##7ZRNThwxEIX3PkXtBiQ2OQIS0mg2YRll6R5Xt5uxq5B/ptUXQJyAEyBOwCpZgrgHJ@mUPQOhQdklUhDsWlXl56/es/oMnRun6fHn7eOPy7sL/3B9dxO@3F8tp2n6houAQAwxBU0dhgiJwfEW1XfOsCEeIFmEkB1G0GQgMhiGlTqGNjsHa/a@Tx4pLSIMVidYLbwc6WnTUwfcVp2BszO0SNBhKs0IbWAveiOwyAfo8qhWcJZjgkETaUgCDaMctUJQJFtEJ4pqySlp8HqDtZ3JCHQSMqW@4rZIcTnf9dv9wPms7gSglA0PNGuETKADi15d02DEUEdnU8/3rsM4a0Q9yhebZsRZve4h1/ZYZW3eiypxXgiLwQSo13ZvRMuhWOxYVhXnAljUoXjbIArg2hZXm5xKs0SXWLKzY0mtIPRJrSj2BmFAaERyF2EJ5kmj4xoMCcHvfDvtd4BDfRA79nO3UzyWet/WtXXcgEy@DuWES7h1V1/9eUJrpG0qHOI7C@hdwR6csj16iXn4p9Lhm8WOgF5V1MHyLxx78cT/9xf@wf49n7D/BvYX) of \$\bar x_i\$; the left column is \$i\$, the right is \$\bar x_i\$. Collapse the "Arguments" element for easier viewing.

---

#### Rules

- You may either:

  - Output the line to STDOUT, or your language's closest alternative; or,
  - Return the line from a function
- You should take no input, aside from an [optional empty input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12681/66833)
- Each language may only be used once. This includes different versions of a language, such as Python 2 and Python 3. Generally, if two languages are considered versions of each other, such as [Seriously and Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), then only one is allowed to be used.
- You may not post 2 answers in a row
- You must wait 1 hour between answers
- The challenge will end when the 74th answer is posted, at which point I will accept an answer of the winner's choice

---

Please format your answer as the following:

```
# [Num]. [Lang], score [score]

    code

[Try it online!]

[Everything else]
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22268/66833)

Comment: ight time to find 74 different languages

Comment: Do you mean "Output the line to STDIN"?

Comment: @tsh I don't know what you're talking about ;)

Comment: "A user's overall score is the arithmetic mean of the scores of all their answers." Does it mean if I stop posting answers now I will be at least tied for first place? Maybe the number of answers posted should have a weight in the score...

Comment: @Leo Currently, yes, that's correct, but I'm open to better scoring systems/suggestions

Comment: Proposed scoring function: sum(#answer/(1+|n-x_i|)) for all answers. #answer is the index of the answer in the chain, later answers with many languages forbidden would be worth more.

Comment: So this is basically an elaborate ploy to rick-roll as many people as possible with your first link - Bravo! :))) Didn't follow it myself so you didn't get me! :P

Comment: Does "irreducible" mean that you have to prove that your own answer is irreducible, or just that anyone who finds a reduction should edit the answer? Since it's really hard to prove that something is irreducible in most languages.

Comment: @AndrewLi If it isn't obviously irreducible (by the definition in the question, not that it's the smallest possible program that outputs the string), then yes, you should demonstrate that your answer is irreducible before posting and include that in the answer

Comment: Since there are only 17 lines with integer values of x_i (based on the table the Jelly program outputs - I can't quite tell how the values are rounded so it might be <17), only 17 answers can get score 0. This means that the winner will probably be one of those 17 (assuming the user who posted it hasn't also posted a non-zero score, which will probably end up being the case for at least one), which makes the competition a bit less interesting. It's also not too unlikely there will be a tie, so what are you going to do about that if it happens?

Comment: Ugh, I wasn't paying attention and missed my chance to score 0 on line 13... that just leaves lines 63 (trivial) and 62 (almost trivial). Always assuming the song even gets that far of course.

Comment: Oh, some of the lines are within 0.05 of an integer... in that case there are a few more opportunities left; 55/56 and 69/70 (55/62/69 (almost) trivial and 56/63/70 trivial); 61/68 (blank output so you need a language where empty programs are an error); 46 (difficult as the line is so long).

Answer (score 7):

## 4. [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), score 0

```
¨You wouldn't get this fromȦ?ØoĠÜy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CKyPxShfL80pyUPPUShfTUEoWSjMxihbSi/NwTy@wPz8g/suDwnMr//wE)

Just wanted to use Husk before someone else could steal it. Simply a (partially) compressed string.

Comment: Funny how `guy` compresses(?) to `ĠÜy`.

Comment: @Makonede It's actually kind of intentional. Husk's compressed strings are designed in a way to use similar characters as much as possible (e.g., "Hello, world!" is `H◄⁰,ω]!`, where `◄` is `l`eft, `⁰` looks like `o`, `ω` looks like `w`, and `]` looks like `D`)

Comment: Oh, and `ĠÜy` actually [gets decoded](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CKIwsOz6n8/x8A "Husk – Try It Online") as `" guy"` (with a leading space) so yes, it's a compression :)

Answer (score 5):

## 7. [Subleq](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Subleq), 28 bytes (7 32-bit words), score 0.3

```
6 3 3
0 0 3
4
```

[Subleq Emulator](http://mazonka.com/subleq/online/hsqjs.cgi)

I am new to Subleq so hopefully this is right.  The first line changes the 3 in address 5 to -1 which makes the second line exit producing no output.  Deleting a word causes an infinite loop. For example, 0 0 0 goes to 0.

Answer (score 4):

## 1. [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), score 0

```
“ŒßỤẸ:IŀėṪƝƓɠi?ṅRṭḄṁ3Ġ»ḣ26
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9qZWxsef//4oCcxZLDn@G7pOG6uDpJxYDEl@G5qsadxpPJoGk/4bmFUuG5reG4hOG5gTPEoMK74bijMjb//w)

```
“ŒßỤẸ:IŀėṪƝƓɠi?ṅRṭḄṁ3Ġ»     We're no strangers to love abcd
                       ḣ26  first 26 chars
```

Comment: I recommend against posting a BF answer as it is very difficult to prove its irreducability.

Comment: @Makonede fair enough

Comment: @Makonede Not necessarily. It is very well possible to write a BF program that is provably irreducible, though such an answer will almost surely be ungolfy and could be conceived as "not a serious contender".

Comment: @Bubbler Never g̶o̶n̶n̶a̶ ̶g̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶u̶p̶ said it was impossible, I just w̶a̶n̶n̶a̶ ̶t̶e̶l̶l̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶f̶e̶e̶l̶i̶n̶g̶ said it would be difficult

Comment: @Bubbler true, though in general, it's only considered "not serious" if, given the specific language and approach you chose, no attempt was made to golf it down. for example, extra spaces, long variables, etc. choosing an ungolfy approach but still showing effort in golfing is valid

Answer (score 4):

## 2. [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), score 0

```
“Youƒ€ the rules and so do I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOcyPzSY5MeNa1RKMlIVSgqzUktVkjMS1EozldIyVfw/P8fAA)

```
“...  # trimmed program
“...  # push "You know the rules and so do I"
      # implicit output
```

<sub>I accidentally opened Settings (Win+I) while typing this explanation.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

## 3. [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), score 0

```
`A ƛ‡ commitment's w∷⟇ I'm ʀ¨ of
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60A%20%C6%9B%E2%80%A1%20commitment%27s%20w%E2%88%B7%E2%9F%87%20I%27m%20%CA%80%C2%A8%20of&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 4):

## 5. [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 131 bytes, score 96.4

```
73.32.106.117.115.116.32.119.97.110:..97.32.116.101.108:..32.121.111.117.32.104.111.119.32.73.39.109.32.102.101:..108.105.110.103.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xDoAwDAN/FMUtFMLEV2ACCTEgFl4fnMBwan2tk2NZn2s/7819qFKLQJsAA@lJSwUTC6OTxCUVfynISBeiMABZzSndHy1ijDZK@94CsMc2iT3Ks8rs/gI)

Here goes a suboptimal language choice, as it can't win against those zero scores anyway.

It is hard to reuse a number in Labyrinth (except for adjacent ones) because each digit command alters the current top of the stack, rather than pushing a new number.

Answer (score 4):

## 10. [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 29 bytes, score 0.8

```
`Nev€ gna run ÂÐ˜ „d Ürt yŒ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qYXB0//9gTmV2woAgZ8KNbmEgcnVuIMOCw5DCmCDChGQgw5wYcnQgecKM//8)

Just compressed the string, outputs `Never gonna run around and desert you`

Somehow the compressor is very nice and fits my need, exactly 28 bytes of string while compressed and adding a leading backtick to decompress gives 29 bytes, then leading to a nice optimal score

Though I think the HTML trick was better

Comment: How are you getting that score? I make this as scoring \$|29-28.2|=0.8\$

Comment: @cairdcoinhering err my bad, sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 3):

## 9. [R](https://www.r-project.org/) version >= 4.1, Score 1.8

```r
\()"Never gonna let you down"
```

A function taking no arguments and returning a string. No TIO link because R 4.1 isn’t yet on TIO.

Apologies for getting the wrong line initially!

Answer (score 3):

## 12. [HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/), score 1.7909090909090892

```
Never gonna say goodby&#101
```

I deleted my older HTML answer 1 hour ago so posting this now

Answer (score 3):

## Line 14, `" "`

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 0 bytes, score 26

```python
[nothing here]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIzmjSMPQQFPz////JgYGAA)

Gotta get Python in here somewhere.

Comment: The empty program also outputs nothing, so this is reducible. Additionally, you were ninja'd

Comment: wait where was I ninja'd

Comment: They've just deleted their answer, never mind

Comment: Was its score better or worse than 26?

Comment: If it's better, I'll delete mine

Comment: No worries, I'll delete mine. It was a tie.

Answer (score 2):

## 6. [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), score 0

```js
_=>'Gotta make you '+"understand"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1k7dPb@kJFEhNzE7VaEyv1RBXVupNC8ltai4JDEvRel/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoam5n8A)

```js
_=>'...'+"..."  # trimmed program
_=>             # return function taking an optional argument _ that returns...
   '...'        # literal...
        +       # concatenated with...
         "..."  # literal
```

Comment: Thankfully, the shortest way to do this in Python is actually a way that irreducibly achieves a minimal score!

Comment: You can exit with a string? lol nice

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Sorta, if `exit` is given a string it just outputs said string to STDERR and exits with code \$1\$. Of course, the exit code can't be a string, but `exit` is a well-known way to golf in Python as STDERR output is allowed

Comment: Although, now that I think about it: given the rules stating `You may either: Output the line to STDOUT, or your language's closest alternative; or, Return the line from a function`, would this even be valid? Python has STDOUT unlike some languages (supposedly?) whose closest to STDOUT is either STDERR or another output method

Comment: Yea, I deliberately overrode the site output defaults, because of answers like these. Outputting to STDERR isn't allowed, the output should go to STDOUT (so `print` with Python)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Fixed

Comment: It's funny how you've explained JS like 05AB1E.

Comment: You’re missing a space in the code as formatted here (but the TIO version and score are correct)

Comment: @NickKennedy Whoops

Comment: @Ausername I use this sort of format for most of my answers.

Answer (score 2):

## 8.  [Splinter](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Splinter), Score 18.4

```
\N\e\v\e\r\ \g\o\n\n\a\ \g\i\v\e\ \y\o\u\ \u\p
```

[Try it online!](https://deadfish.surge.sh/splinter#XE5cZVx2XGVcclwgXGdcb1xuXG5cYVwgXGdcaVx2XGVcIFx5XG9cdVwgXHVccA==)

Note: Apologies for the edit, I thought we were aiming for a higher score.

**this** outputs `Never gonna give you up`

Answer (score 2):

## 11. Unary, 25247105318448659498226527583287720106787200954491263487845422435915430598123234439645367425137855414888675036 bytes - Score very close to that

Since it's impossible to beat those 0-pointers...

Compiles to `+[>>>-[-->+<<+<]<<+]>+++.<<<<+++.>.<.<<.>------.>++.<<---.-..>>------.<.>++++++.++.>.<----.<.>>+++.<<<+.++++++.>.<.-----.` in brainfrick - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxRCoAwDEMPFJoTlFxk7EMFQQQ/BM9f143mIw2vJPu7Xc/5HXcEmiRrZoI7vA/rAkAfyiv6yJRNUfOVyUgV9eQprkbBWkqOWluViB8)

Comment: Do you have a proof this is irreducible?

Comment: @CommandMaster No, but I spent five minutes trying to golf it, so hopefully it is.

Comment: @CommandMaster That is, golf the BF.

Comment: The unary program is definitely not irreducible. As as long as there exists a shorter brainfuck program (it does), this can be reduced to it.

Comment: @ovs If there is a shorter BF program, I haven't found it.

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##NYxRCoAwDEMPFJoTlFxk7EMFQQQ/BM9f143mIw2vJPu7Xc/5HXcEmiRrZoI7vA/rAkAfyiv6yJRNUfOVyUgV9eQprkbBWkqOWluViB8) is a 121-byter generated with [bfbrute](https://github.com/ksabry/bfbrute). Note this is still not optimal, we don't even know if the [`Hello, World!` answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163590/64121) is optimal.

Comment: @ovs Ok, will update.

Answer (score 2):

## 15. [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), score 0.5

```
üy ♫ε╖nÖG°∟2♦︎½►±ç╧∟X)÷A•σ←
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8179200eeeb76e9947f81c3204ab10f187cf1c5829f64107e51b&i=)

Prints “We've known each other for so long”.

Answer (score 2):

## 19. [Grok](https://github.com/AMiller42/Grok-Language), 50 bytes, score 22.1

```
hqj`ti yalp annog er'ew dna emag eht wonk eWi
W{lY
```

[Try it Online!](http://grok.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=hqj%60ti%20yalp%20annog%20er%27ew%20dna%20emag%20eht%20wonk%20eWi%0AW%7BlY&inputs=)

Explanation:

```
h                                              # Start the IP moving left
   `ti yalp annog er'ew dna emag eht wonk eWi  # Push the string 'We know the game and we're gonna play it' to the stack.
  j                                            # Change the IP to move down
  l                                            # Change the IP to move right
   Y                                           # Duplicate the top of the stack to the register
W                                              # Print the value in the register as a character
 {                                             # If the top of the stack is 0, rotate IP direction clockwise
 q                                             # Terminate program
```

Comment: Looks like a Lovecraftian esolang, is `Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn` a valid Grok program? Does it awake a long time sunken Ancient? Now I'm afraid to try..

Comment: @Kaddath It's actually a pretty simple language. I added an explanation if you're curious how it works. It pretty much just pushes the string and prints each character until it reaches the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

## 20. [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), score 1.1

```
00000000: e54c 1a26 90b8 f59b c710 0b14 f216 4647  .L.&..........FG
00000010: e7b7 bf31 1a85 6a0a 7a05 e8              ...1..j.z..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcwxDoMwDEbhnVP8E6NlQxIHDtAuXCJGCRKiI0svH0CtkPj292w32/Kyf2rlvxHZuxmSuoCBLaL4wTCrMNjEoXQS4IJTgCZq6fZ6N7@DXA81hZVezlH0CIkTNLFHjng4QyFa6UtU6wE)

Uses the BB96 encoding to encode "And if you ask me how I'm feeling"

Answer (score 2):

### 24. [Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/excel), Score <s>0</s> 3

```
Never gonna let you down
```

*+3 score due to reducibility error*

Answer (score 1):

## 13. [DOG](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DOG), Score 15

```
bark "Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you "
```

I can't figure out how to adapt the interpreter to TIO, so you'll have to download it.

Comment: Can't you remove the space before the last `"`?

Comment: Due to an interpreter glitch, the string's last character isn't outputted.

Answer (score 1):

## 16. [PHP](https://php.net/), 34 bytes, Score 7.4

```php
<?="Your heart's been aching but";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WKTK/tEghIzWxqES9WCEpNTVPITE5IzMvXSGptETJ@v9/AA)

PHP was of course needed here, for this very difficult line, and it has not enough pride left to care so much about its score anymore!

Comment: You can [remove the `<?="` and the `";`](https://tio.run/##K8go@P8/Mr@0SCEjNbGoRL1YISk1NU8hMTkjMy9dIam05P9/AA)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I expected this one.. If you do it it's not PHP anymore, but Text.. the rules are borderline here because we usually allow the PHP tag to be omitted from count except when it's `<?=` because it stands for `echo`. But you cannot remove the tag completely and still have it parsed as PHP. If you try to execute `Your heart's been aching but` in -r mode you'll get a Parse Error

Comment: @Kaddath PHP is a hypertext preprocessor, so it makes sense that you can just write plain text.

Comment: @xigoi I don't really see the point here, you can type anything in a HTML page but only what you type inside `<script>` tags is Javascript, and this doesn't make plain text or HTML answers valid Javascript answers.. The rules can be a bit blurry for PHP, but all the debates I've seen revolve around ignoring the `<?php` in the byte count, not that everything ouside the tags is PHP too (see my previous comment about -r mode). Anyway that's how I interpret the rules and craft my answers, the others can do differently, I don't downvote plain text PHP answers or raise debates there..

Answer (score 1):

## 17. [Underload](https://github.com/catseye/stringie), score 0.5

```
(You're too shy to say it)S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K81LSS3KyU9M@f9fIzK/VL0oVaEkP1@hOKMSSCsUJ1YqZJZoBv//DwA)

Fairly simple.

```
(You're too shy to say it)S

(You're too shy to say it)   Push this string to the top of the stack.
                          S  Print the top of the stack.
```

Answer (score 1):

## 21. [COW](https://esolangs.org/wiki/COW), Score 4474.4

```
OOOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMMMmoOMMMMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomOoMoOmoOmoomOoMMMmoOMMMMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomOoMoOmoOmoomOoMMMmoOMMMMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomOoMoOmoOmooOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOomOoMMMmoOmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOoOOOmoOOOOmOomOoMMMmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomOomOoMMMmoOmoOMMMMOOMOomoOMoOmOomoomoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoOMoomOo
```

[Try it online](https://frank-buss.de/cow.html)(program will need to be pasted in)

Outputs `Don't tell me you're too blind to see`

Answer (score 1):

## 22. [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), score 1.7

```cs
class P{static void Main(){}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/PzknsbhYIaC6uCSxJDNZoSw/M0XBNzEzT0Ozurb2/38A)

A minimal C# program that does nothing. I think any less than this and there’s no valid entry point.

Answer (score 1):

## 25.  [Quarterstaff](https://github.com/Destructible-Watermelon/Quarterstaff), score 98.6

```
111>o101>a110>b114>r78!a!118!a!r!32!103!o!b!b!97!32!r!117!b!32!97!r!o!117!b!100!32!97!b!100!32!100!a!115!a!r!116!32!121!o!117!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxRDoAgDEPPshusoKI/3AUS@SVOPD9uSMySra/Nej1J2il3S6X0DiBWMGICOGZgiRJ2SgTYFvKOwJ4qZZ0jGIuGQUmlGqLZx2Ce3q/tWNc6uoBtmA7zp/cX)

Answer (score 0):

## 18.  Deadfish~, 291.8 score

```
{{i}ddd}iiic{iiii}dddciiiiic{d}cdddddcic{{d}iii}ic{{i}d}dddc{dd}iic{{d}iii}ic{iiiiii}iiiiiic{i}iiiciiiiic{d}ddc{{d}iii}ddc{{i}ddd}iiiiiciiicic{i}ddc{{d}i}iiic{{i}d}dddc{d}dddddc{d}iiic{ii}dc{{d}ii}iiic{{i}ddd}iiiiiic{{d}ii}dddc{iiiiii}iiiiiiciiicc{i}dc{{d}ii}iic{{i}ddd}ic{i}ddcddddddciiiiic{d}iiic{{d}iii}dc{{i}dd}dcdc
```

[Try it online!](https://deadfish.surge.sh/#Wksd9XuybL/6Jgv/gJvZ//4m3oqbL7/5v6Tb0VMBQJlEBN7/NvRf5sv/oIImX+beqJsvv/m9//83omL5t6UTZf/QJt6X/zAUCCTL5t6Umy/+pl/n//8BN6Jt6L5sv988)

Answer (score 0):

## 23.  [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak),Score 4370.9

```
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDc3hDzWHvQ2r6dTS0Rv03mgNGQ2PUt6N@Gs2fo7E66rvRVsNoiTNae476ZdS3o37R/P//v64jAA)

Sorry about the mess. I have no idea how to efficiently get large numbers in Brain-flak.

Outputs `Never gonna give you up`